# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory

Tags: spring

I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory` error while running mule application. I checked jettison-1.1.jar jar is already there in my application folder lib directory but still I am getting this error.
I am getting this error while initialising Spring batch job repository.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver.<init>(JettisonMappedXmlDriver.java:36)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.init(XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:67)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.afterPropertiesSet(XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:62)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:182)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
```

Comment: Do you add it to your classpath? How do you run your application?

Comment: We are deploying the application on mule server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jettison.jar` file to your project.

[Download from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjettison13jar.htm)

Comment: I already have jettison-1.1.jar in my project lib directory that contains org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory class.

Comment: @sach Then check if it exists in class path or not.

Comment: My application lib folder contains all the required jar files. jettison-1.1.jar also there in the lib folder and lib folder is added into class path. I think somehow application is not looking into jettison-1.1.jar for the required class.

Comment: I found the issue. Mule server has xstream-1.2.2-osgi.jar that also contains MappedXMLOutputFactory class. If I removed this jar then application work fine. How do we force to use jettison-1.1.jar?